# how do i paginate fancybox navigation thumbnails

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a lot of photos in my fancybox gallery and the thumbnail navigation leaks off the side of the page.

So I want to paginate the visible thumbnail navigation to 5 or so with arrows or something along those lines.

I am not the best at js (I am learning) but I do understand html.

http://ryansamul.com/dark/gallery-subject-new.html

The following is a truncated version of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {

                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs : {
                width : 100,
                height : 100
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>


<div class="one-fifth">
                <p>
                    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="images/gallery/subject/1.jpg" ><img src="images/gallery/subject/thumbs/1.png" width="158" height="158" alt=" "/></a>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="one-fifth">
                <p>
                    <a href="images/gallery/subject/2.jpg" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb"><img src="images/gallery/subject/thumbs/2.png" width="158" height="158" alt=" " /></a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-fifth">
                <p>
                    <a href="images/gallery/subject/3.jpg" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb"><img src="images/gallery/subject/thumbs/3.png" width="158" height="158" alt=" " /></a> 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-fifth">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your thumbnails to just 'fit' in the width of the browser, you could change a few of your CSS elements to have widths of 100%.  If you change these three, you will get there.

```
.center {
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-container {    
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then, as you change the width of the browser, fewer or more images will fit in each row.

Comment: That seemed to work well with the thumbnails in the main page, but im referring specifically to the 'fancybox' navigation thumbnails that appear at the bottom of the fancybox lightbox.  i want to keep 5 or so visible with a scroll to see more.